# How to solve equation with unknown nth degree

Tags: exponential-function, radicals

How it is possible to solve this equation

$$3*2^\sqrt x+2^{3-\sqrt x}=25$$

I have used formula $x^y=y^x$

But seems that it is not right answer.
I just don't know hot to get rid of $\sqrt x$ exponent.

Comment: Multiply through by $2^{\sqrt x}$, then treat it as a quadratic in $2^{\sqrt x}$

Comment: "*I have used formula $x^y=y^x$*".... that worries me... what formula do you think that is?  $3^2=3\cdot 3=9$ but $2^3=2\cdot 2\cdot 2=8$... so you have $3^2\neq 2^3$ and in general in most cases $x^y\neq y^x$

Comment: @JMoravitz Oh, sorry, that was very stupid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**hint**

Put $$2^\sqrt {x}=z. $$

it becomes

$$3z+\frac {8}{z}=25$$
or

$$3z^2-25z+8=0$$

with
$\Delta=625-96=(23)^2$.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply by $2^{\sqrt x}$ and rewrite as

$$3\cdot\left(2^{\sqrt x}\right)^2-25\cdot2^{\sqrt x}+2^{3}=0.$$

Then

$$2^\sqrt{x}=\frac{25\pm23}{6}=\frac13\text{ or }8$$

and $$x=\left(\log_2\frac13\right)^2\text{ or }9.$$